# StackPanel Orientation in xaml

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-4.0, stackpanel

I got a weird problem on my xaml, in a stackPanel.

My stackPanel contains a textbox, and a button.

This should be on the same line (if possible, depending on the text width).
The problem is :

if the stackPanel have `Orientation="Vertical"`, the button will go to the line bellow the text.
if the stackPanel have `Orientation="Horizontal"` , the line will not doing any break line, so all the line will go out of my grid.

```
<StackPanel Name="spRemplir"
            Grid.Row="2"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="6"
            Width="560"
            Margin="5,5,5,5"
            Orientation="Horizontal"
            VerticalAlignment="Center">
 <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold"
            Text={Binding Text}
            TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
 <Button Name="btRemplir"
         Margin="5,0,0,0"
         Width="150"
         Content="Remplir"/>
</StackPanel>
```

How can I obtain a stackPanel, that will break lines if necessary, and have a text and a button on the same line?

**Update with Wrapanel thanks to Eli Arbel :**

```
 <toolkit:WrapPanel  Name="spRemplir"
                     Grid.Row="2"
                     Grid.ColumnSpan="6"
                     Margin="5,5,5,5"
                     Width="560"
                     Orientation="Horizontal">
   <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold"
              Text={Binding Text}
              TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
   <Button Name="btRemplir"
           Content="Remplir"/>
</toolkit:WrapPanel>
```

But, the button still on the next line, while there is enough space after the text on the same line.

Itried removing the Width on the panel, but then, there is no more wrapping...

I don't understand. Even if there is stackPanel on the same Grid, they should not disturb the wrap panel right?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe the problem is hardcoded width od StackPanel (Width="560"). If it's in the grid, it should not be necessary and it might result in what you described.

Comment: @EliArbel your right. Add silverlight tag. Buli : if i remove the Width, il will not take a break line.

Answer (score 2):

You can try a `WrapPanel` from the [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/). Note this panel will not allow you to stretch the items to the container width.

You should also look into removing the fixed `Width` of the panel.

Comment: Ok thanks. I'm trying, but, which way is he different from a Stackpanel? I see only the same properties in the two of them.

Comment: Indeed. Weirdly, he starts displaying at the half of the cantainer. But it is the only element on the row... I will search what's wrong.

Comment: I can show more xaml, but in a private discuss. How can we start one?

Answer (score 1):

Try using a Grid instead of a StackPanel.  The problem with StackPanel is that they do not report up the Visual Tree that they are out of room.  This is not a bug, it's just the way they are and it's appropriate when you need it.  But I avoid them except on the innermost elements.  But don't have StackPanels in StackPanels as you will lose TextWrapping/Scrolling and just have elements fall of the right or bottom of the page.

Second, make sure that your outer container is Set so that the width is Constrained. For example, in your layout root, give it one Column, and set the Width for * which means = "The available space, but not more"

Once you have your outer container constrained, then your TextBlock will wrap properly.

Greg

Comment: Well my stackPanel are children of a grid(so I must define a width in it, to have a good wrapping?). Isn't it a lot of work to define a grid(with column and row definitions) each time? Just asking. And thanks for your explanations.

Comment: I think I will do some "homework" on xaml best structure ^^. Thank you for your advices My code were not really made the best way it seems.

Comment: @Zaphod Yes, it's a bit of typing, but it gives you nice layout that will dynamically change.  Check out this site I made in all Silverlight: OfficeExtreme.com

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a WrapPanel instead stack panel: http://wpftutorial.net/WrapPanel.html

Comment: Sorry for confusing you, I forgot to add the tag silverlight.